# Same form partial, params present on create, but absent on update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a form partial that I reuse for create and update actions. On hitting the create action, I get the expected params hash but the same doesn't happen on update. Here's my form partial.

```
<%= form_for :track, url: url, method: method do |f| %>
  ...
<% end %>
```

Which I then call from a view:

```
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { url: tracks_path, method: :post } %>
```

The corresponding route:

```
post '/:user/:playlist/tracks' => 'tracks#create', as: :tracks
```

And the controller action:

```
def create
  render plain: params[:track].inspect
end
```

On submit, I receive all the fields of that form alright as a nested hash of `params[:track]`. Oddly, I don't get what I'm expecting for the update action:

```
# view
<%= render partial: 'form', locals: { url: update_track_path, method: :patch } %>

# route
patch '/:user/:playlist/:track' => 'tracks#update', as: :update_track

# controller 
def update
  render plain: params[:track].inspect
end
```

I'm expecting `params[:track]` in this case to also be a nested hash but its content is instead a string. And this string happens to be the value of `:track` in  `/:user/:playlist/:track`.

I'm confused. How do I get back the nested hash?

Comment: I am a bit confused, can you share some of the log output that shows how the data is passed back to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is a naming conflict. `params[:track]` is being defined in two ways:

- the route `/:user/:playlist/:track` defines `params[:track]` as that segment of the url
- your form defines `params[:track]` as a the hash of values

To work around this, change the param name in your URL. For example, change the url pattern to `/:user/:playlist/:track_name`, then access the URL param as `params[:track_name]`.

That way, there won't be a conflict between URL params and form params!